# Can I schedule workloads based on namespace in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

The question says everything really - is it possible to schedule a Pod based on the namespace it is assigned to?

Comment: What exactly do you mean here? Are you looking for conditional scheduling, ie `if namespace == "foo"; do $x with pod` ?

Comment: No, just to be able to configure the cluster such that if a Pod is created in a particular namespace, it is scheduled to a particular set of Nodes (i.e. the ability to define nodeaffinity rules per namespace) - nothing more generic

Comment: It just seems like a very useful feature considering RBAC permissions can be defined per namespace, so wanted to check whether it was possible or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not built in as far as I know, but there's a couple of ways you could do it:

Create a mutating webhook that modifies the pod affinity rules if the `namespace == something`. Using something like this: https://github.com/slok/kubewebhook

Using the PodNodeSelector admission controller: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/

Using the PodPreset admission controller:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/podpreset/